# @media query and "left:x%" is applying % of @width define in @media not the browser/parent element width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using bootstrap to implement the responsive web design. I am facing issue to apply "left" property as %. What I found is, instead of taking the % of total browser width, it takes the % of @media width define which really breaking the responsive nature of application.

```
.image-container {
  width: 173px;
  top: -69px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -86px;
  max-width: 336px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .image-container {
    left: 63%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 831px) {
  .image-container {
    top: -91px;
    left: 80%;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .image-container {
    left: 85%;
  }
}
```

I found following

```
1. At >1280 width, left=1280*.85 is used
2. At > 831, left=831*.80 us used
3. At > 660, left=660*.63 is used
```

Following is HTML markup snippet

```
<div class="bottom-section">         
        <div class="parent-container">                        
            <div class="image-container">
                <img class="card-art"  src="/img/application/cardarts/thumbnails/img.png"> 
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

Following is parent container css

```
.parent-container {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 68px;
  max-width: 970px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
@media (min-width: 660px) {
  .parent-container {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

This is a surprising behavior for me. My understanding is, left=x% should alwasy look for parent element and apply the % of that. I am new to media query and using bootstrap to implement the responsive web design.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/bvt3kw7y/) to play with.

Comment: What's the parent's `position:` attribute?

Comment: i do have position:relative, I have added markup and parent css details.

Comment: Do you think that this is not @media query issue, instead it is position:absolute and dependencies on parent element to have position:relative?

Comment: *Fiddle added to play with*

Comment: Thanks, I realized that i max-width: 970px; in parent element was causing this issue. After i removed, it works fine.